# symfony form choice field : set choices option default data from external datasource

Tags: php, symfony

How to populate choices option with an external data array ?

```
$builder->add('gender', 'choice', array(
    'choices' => [array from webservice or other class]
));
```

documentation show only simple static array
http://symfony.com/fr/doc/2.7/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choices

I tried it :

controller :

```
$event = new Event();
$form = $this->createForm(new EventType($this->get('api')), $event);
```

form :

```
class EventType extends AbstractType
{
    protected $myservice;

    public function __construct($myservice)
    {
        $this->myservice = $myservice;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('titre')
            ->add('id_rubrique', 'choice', array(
                'choices' => $this->myservice->getRubriques
        ;
    }

    ....
}
```

**Is it the right solution ?**

Comment: Are you using EventListeners?

Comment: Either that or change your Form into a service and inject the dependancy through the service and use a constructor. http://symfony.com/fr/doc/current/reference/dic_tags.html#form-type-extension

Comment: or pass it in via the controller.

Answer (score 2):

Define your form as a service:

```
services:
    my.form:
        class: EventType
        arguments:
            - @api
```

Then in controller:

```
$event = new Event();
$form = $this->createForm('my.form', $event);
```

Answer (score 0):

example

```
->add('education', 'choice', array('label' => 'Education *','choices' => $this->getEducation(), 'required' => true, 'empty_value' => 'select', 'empty_data'  => null))
```

$this->getEducation() is array

//Array ( 'option1Value' => 'option1Name'...